# plot two groups of wind direction

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, data-visualization, scatterplot

I have two groups of wind direction and I want to use spoke plot in R peogramme

I search about it in R programme using ?spoke plot but i cant found any

information .

for more detials

the first group of  wind direction (wind of GAZA X)

X=c(150,160,160,180,240,240,180,160,
200,180,180,190,230,240,190,210,
200,190,180,220,260,270,240,190,
200,170,190,250,280,220,200,150,
160,140,160,260,290,290,210,180,
210,160,180,280,300,310,310,250,
170,160,170,260,290,310,260,180,
190,170,150,270,300,320,320,220,
160,160,150,260,300,320,300,230,
160,160,160,240,300,280,200,160,
130,140,150,170,25,240,150,120,
160,160,160,180,210,180,180,160)

the second group of wind direction (Khan Yunis Y)

Y= c(135,137,140,139,184,225,251,127,
 175,172,167,170,199,238,243,178,
 169,167,157,165,210,273,276,191,
 179,158,141,157,254,279,245,191,
 158,136,147,254,306,303,229,177,
 171,127,142,264,304,319,298,197,
 160,149,160,262,290,312,315,190,
 133,147,133,269,300,315,334,222,
 134,134,134,234,260,320,306,201,
 154,139,139,173,168,308,240,168,
 123,133,133,143,111,282,212,111,
 137,139,139,150,131,205,171,131)